# Wondering if there is a formula equivalent of copyTo?

Tags: google-sheets, copy, google-sheets-formula

Trying to copy from one sheet `sheet1` to another `sheet2` in google sheets.

As much script as I have running, I would like to accomplish this via a formula instead.  Where values are involved,

**EG:** `=sheet1!A1"`, works fine.

But when it comes to copying a formula as is, so it works on the new sheet, I cannot figure it out.

**EG:**  In cell `D6` on `sheet1` the formula `=IF($G6<=$F6,sum($E6-$G6),0)` is written.

I would like to copy that formula to `cell D6` on `sheet2`, so it utilizes the information on sheet2 and does not reference sheet1.

`copyTo` in script would accomplish exactly that.

Is there an equivalent via formula?

Moreover, I'm looking to have this happen automatically (hence, the formula), so I do not have to address multiple spreadsheets manually to get this done.  Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know there are no Formulas to do that, but how about referencing the Sheet formula using [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) with Apps Script?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll take a look and see if/how it could work.